# Activate Cross-Site Publishing with CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, cross-site-publishing

We are currently evaluating on how to enable/configure [Cross-Site Publishing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163225.aspx) with the usage of CSOM.

When using Server Side Object Model (SSOM) the documentation recommends to use the [PublishingCatalogUtility class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingcatalogutility.aspx)

Is there any equivalent to use on client side (CSOM, JSOM, REST...) available? Does anyone have any experience on that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current version of the CSOM library it is not possible to configure the Cross-Site Publishing features.

The issue can only be solved by using the server side libraries.

There may be an implementation for client side libraries in the upcoming SharePoint 2016 version. We will see.